# cloning multiple VMs in parallel with multithreaded PowerCLI

Tags: vmware, powercli

I've taken on the task of cloning a ton of VMs in VMware.  Rather than clicking hundreds of times through the clone wizard, I'd like to automate this as much as possible.

I've got the template machine already configured and "sealed."  Once it's cloned and powered on, the newly-cloned instance will boot up, sit there for a while while it syspreps, etc.  This takes about 20 minutes or so.

I found a very nice [script over on MSFT TechNet](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/c74b4a23-e4ec-4829-b38e-54252b40fdec) that does everything I need it to do.  I've modified it a little bit so I don't have to change a value and re-save the script for each step of the process.  Instead of the $Step counter throughout the script, I've simply replaced it with some Start-Sleep delays.  At this point, it works fine and successfully clones all the machines that it reads in from a CSV file.  Each machine takes about 35 minutes before it's ready to go (machine is moved to a different AD OU).

The only problem is it's running all serially, waiting for the entire process (clone, change VLAN, boot machine and wait for domain join, and move final machine object to a different AD OU) to finish before starting another clone.

What I'd really like to somehow is multithread it to make the whole operation faster.  I've found in testing that cloning within vSphere starts to slow down once about five separate clone jobs are running, so I'd like to modify this script to run four clones (doing the whole workflow) at once.

Any ideas?  I can paste the code if needed.

Answer (score 2):

You can at max clone 8 vms in parallel from one template. If you run new-vm with -RunAsync. With -RunAsync The command returns immediately and the output consists of one or more Task objects.

if you want to clone multiple VMs Following should help. just loop it.

```
Write-host "Deploying VM " -ForegroundColor Green -NoNewline; Write-Host $vmname -ForegroundColor Yellow
get-OScustomizationspec $cs | get-OScustomizationNicMapping | set-OSCustomizationNicMapping -IpMode UseStaticIP -IpAddress $vm.IP -SubnetMask $vm.subnet -DefaultGateway $vm.gateway -Dns $vm.Dns1, $vm.Dns2

$vms = New-VM -Name $vm.Name -Location $vm.cluster -VMhost $vm.vmhost -Template $vm.template -Datastore $vm.datastore -OSCustomizationSpec $cs -confirm:$false **-RunAsync**

if ($vm1.error) {
    Write-Host "Error in deploying $vmname" -ForegroundColor Red
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is a script I wrote over the past couple of days that deploys a VM template to about 650 of our servers. It deploys it from 3 different VM Hosts in different data centers across the country. It deploys 5 from the Irving location, 15 from Plano, and 15 from Atlanta at the same time. It runs between 7PM and 6AM Mon-Fri, and all day Saturday and Sunday. It exits if it runs any other time.

I ran out of time when trying to figure out how to pass more than one parameter to a function when calling that function using Start-Job, so I just created a separate function for the three locations instead.

Using this script we were able to deploy a new RDC image to over 650 locations on nights and weekends in about a week.

param(
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
    [string]$InputFile = $null
    )

```
Get-Module -ListAvailable VMware* | Import-Module | Out-Null
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$Global:CompletedHosts = @()

$MAXVMHostCount = 50
$IrvingMaxJobs = 6
$PlanoMaxJobs = 15
$AtlantaMaxJobs = 15

Function Add-VMHosts() {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][int]$MAXVMHostCount,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][string]$InputFile
    )

    $AllVMHosts = @()

    If ($InputFile) {
        $AllVMHosts = Get-Content $InputFile
    }
    Else {
        $Jobs = (Get-Job).Name
        If ($Jobs -ne $null) {
            $Jobs = $Jobs.Trim("-TXINTATL")
        }

        ForEach ($Server in (Get-ADComputer -Server *************** -SearchBase "OU=************************" -Filter { Name -like "**********" })) {
            If ($Server.Name.Substring(10,1) -eq "0") {
                $IP = "10." + $Server.Name.Substring(11,1) + "."
            }
            Else {
                $IP = "10." + $Server.Name.Substring(10,2) + "."
            }
            If ($Server.Name.Substring(12,2) -eq "00") {
                $IP += "100"
            }
            ElseIf ($Server.Name.Substring(12,1) -eq "0") {
                $IP += $Server.Name.Substring(13,1)
            }
            Else {
                $IP += $Server.Name.Substring(12,2)
            }
            $IP += ".252"

            If ($IP -notin $Global:CompletedHosts -and $IP -notin $Jobs) {
                $AllVMHosts = $AllVMHosts + $IP
            }
        }
    }

    Connect-VIServer ******************** -User "********************" -Password "********************" | Out-Null

    $CurrentVMHostCount = (Get-VMHost -Location (Get-Datacenter "Profit Centers")).Count

    $HostCount = 0
    ForEach ($VMHost in $AllVMHosts) {
        If ($HostCount -ge ($MaxVMHostCount - $CurrentVMHostCount)) {
            Break
        }
        Else {
            $AddFailed = $false
            $ConnectFailed = $false
            $Test = $null

            $Test = Get-VMHost $VMHost -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
            If (!$Test -and (Test-Connection $VMHost -Quiet)) {
                Try {
                    Connect-VIServer $VMHost -User "********************" -Password "********************" -WarningAction SilentlyContinue | Out-Null
                }
                Catch {
                    $ConnectFailed = $true
                }

                If (!$ConnectFailed -and (Get-VMHost $VMHost -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Get-VM -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Where { $_.Name -like "*********************" }) -eq $null -and (Test-Connection $VMHost -Quiet)) {
                    Set-VMHost -VMHost $VMHost -LicenseKey "********************" | Out-Null
                    Disconnect-VIServer -Server $VMHost -Confirm:$false | Out-Null

                    Add-VMHost $VMHost -Location (Get-DataCenter -Name "Profit Centers") -User "********************" -Password "********************" -Force:$true -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Out-Null
                    Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
                    Write-Host "$VMHost added to vCenter successfully"

                    $myVMHost = Get-VMHost $VMHost
                    $myVMHost | Get-VirtualPortGroup | Get-NicTeamingPolicy | Set-NicTeamingPolicy -InheritLoadBalancingPolicy $true -InheritNetworkFailoverDetectionPolicy $true -InheritNotifySwitches $true -InheritFailback $true -InheritFailoverOrder $true -WarningAction SilentlyContinue | Out-Null
                    $myVMHost | Get-VirtualPortGroup | Get-SecurityPolicy | Set-SecurityPolicy -AllowPromiscuousInherited $true -ForgedTransmitsInherited $true -MacChangesInherited $true | Out-Null

                    ForEach ($PortGroup in (Get-VirtualPortGroup -VMHost $VMHost)) {
                        $netSys = Get-View (Get-VMHost -Name $VMHost).ExtensionData.ConfigManager.NetworkSystem
                        $spec = (Get-VirtualPortGroup -Name $PortGroup.Name -VMHost $VMHost).ExtensionData.Spec
                        $spec.Policy.ShapingPolicy.Enabled = $null
                        $netSys.UpdatePortgroup($PortGroup.Name,$spec)
                    }

                    $DisconnectedNICs = Get-VMHostNetworkAdapter -VMHost $VMHost -Physical | Where-Object { $_.BitRatePerSec -eq "0" }
                    If (($DisconnectedNICs.Count -gt 0)) {
                        If (($DisconnectedNICs.DeviceName).Contains("vmnic0")) {
                            $myVMHost | Get-VirtualSwitch -Name vSwitch0 | Get-NicTeamingPolicy | Set-NicTeamingPolicy -MakeNicActive vmnic1,vmnic0 | Out-Null
                        }
                    }
                    $HostCount++
                }
                ElseIf ($ConnectFailed) {
                    Write-Host "Failed to connect to $VMHost" -ForegroundColor Yellow
                }
                Else {
                    Write-Host "$VMHost already has RDC Image" -ForegroundColor Yellow
                    If ($VMHost.Name -notin $Global:CompletedHosts) {
                        $Global:CompletedHosts = $Global:CompletedHosts + $VMHost.Name
                    }
                }
            }
            Else {
                Write-Host "$VMHost already exists in vCenter" -ForegroundColor Yellow
            }
        }
    }

    Get-AlarmDefinition "Network uplink redundancy lost" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Set-AlarmDefinition -Enabled $false | Out-Null
    Get-AlarmDefinition "Network uplink redundancy lost" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Set-AlarmDefinition -Enabled $true | Out-Null

    Disconnect-VIServer -Server * -Confirm:$false
}

Function CopyVMToHostIrving([string]$VMHost) {

    Connect-VIServer ******************** -User "********************" -Password "********************" | Out-Null

    If ((Get-VMHost $VMHost | Get-VM | Where { $_.Name -like "CED-RDC-PC*" }) -eq $null) {
        $NewVMName = "CED-RDC-PC" + (Get-VMHost $VMHost | Get-VM | Where { $_.Name -like "CED-DC-PC*" }).Name.Substring(9,4)

        New-VM -VMHost $VMHost -Name $NewVMName -Datastore (Get-VMHost $VMHost | Get-VM | Where { $_.Name -like "CED-DC-PC*" } | Get-Datastore).Name -Template "W2k19Std-Template-TX" -OSCustomizationSpec "Windows Server 2019 Customizations" | Out-Null

        Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
        Start-VM $NewVMName | Out-Null
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 5

        If ((Get-VMHost $VMHost | Get-VM | Where { $_.Name -like "CED-RDC-PC*" }) -eq $null -or (Get-VMHost $VMHost | Get-VM | Where { $_.Name -like "CED-RDC-PC*" }).PowerState -eq “PoweredOff”) {
            Exit
        }

        Write-Verbose -Message "Verifying that Customization for VM $NewVMName has started ..." -Verbose
        While($True) {
            $DCvmEvents = Get-VIEvent -Entity $NewVMName
            $DCstartedEvent = $DCvmEvents | Where { $_.GetType().Name -eq "CustomizationStartedEvent" }
            If ($DCstartedEvent) {
                Break
            }
            Else {
                Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
            }
        }

        Write-Verbose -Message "Customization of VM $NewVMName has started. Checking for Completed Status......." -Verbose
        While($True) {
            $DCvmEvents = Get-VIEvent -Entity $NewVMName
            $DCSucceededEvent = $DCvmEvents | Where { $_.GetType().Name -eq "CustomizationSucceeded" }
            $DCFailureEvent = $DCvmEvents | Where { $_.GetType().Name -eq "CustomizationFailed" }
            If ($DCFailureEvent) {
                Write-Warning -Message "Customization of VM $NewVMName failed" -Verbose
                Break
            }
            If ($DCSucceededEvent) {
                Break
            }
            Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
        }

        Write-Verbose -Message "Customization of VM $NewVMName Completed Successfully!" -Verbose

        Start-Sleep -Seconds 30
        Write-Verbose -Message "Waiting for VM $NewVMName to complete post-customization reboot." -Verbose
        Wait-Tools -VM $NewVMName -TimeoutSeconds 500 | Out-Null
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 30

        Shutdown-VMGuest $NewVMName -Confirm:$false | Out-Null
    }

    Disconnect-VIServer -Server * -Confirm:$false
}

Function CopyVMToHostPlano([string]$VMHost) {

    Connect-VIServer ******************** -User "********************" -Password "********************" | Out-Null

    If ((Get-VMHost $VMHost | Get-VM | Where { $_.Name -like "CED-RDC-PC*" }) -eq $null) {
        $NewVMName = "CED-RDC-PC" + (Get-VMHost $VMHost | Get-VM | Where { $_.Name -like "CED-DC-PC*" }).Name.Substring(9,4)

        New-VM -VMHost $VMHost -Name $NewVMName -Datastore (Get-VMHost $VMHost | Get-VM | Where { $_.Name -like "CED-DC-PC*" } | Get-Datastore).Name -Template "W2k19Std-Template-INT" -OSCustomizationSpec "Windows Server 2019 Customizations" | Out-Null

        Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
        Start-VM $NewVMName | Out-Null
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 5

        If ((Get-VMHost $VMHost | Get-VM | Where { $_.Name -like "CED-RDC-PC*" }) -eq $null -or (Get-VMHost $VMHost | Get-VM | Where { $_.Name -like "CED-RDC-PC*" }).PowerState -eq “PoweredOff”) {
            Exit
        }

        Write-Verbose -Message "Verifying that Customization for VM $NewVMName has started ..." -Verbose
        While($True) {
            $DCvmEvents = Get-VIEvent -Entity $NewVMName
            $DCstartedEvent = $DCvmEvents | Where { $_.GetType().Name -eq "CustomizationStartedEvent" }
            If ($DCstartedEvent) {
                Break
            }
            Else {
                Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
            }
        }

        Write-Verbose -Message "Customization of VM $NewVMName has started. Checking for Completed Status......." -Verbose
        While($True) {
            $DCvmEvents = Get-VIEvent -Entity $NewVMName
            $DCSucceededEvent = $DCvmEvents | Where { $_.GetType().Name -eq "CustomizationSucceeded" }
            $DCFailureEvent = $DCvmEvents | Where { $_.GetType().Name -eq "CustomizationFailed" }
            If ($DCFailureEvent) {
                Write-Warning -Message "Customization of VM $NewVMName failed" -Verbose
                Break
            }
            If ($DCSucceededEvent) {
                Break
            }
            Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
        }

        Write-Verbose -Message "Customization of VM $NewVMName Completed Successfully!" -Verbose

        Start-Sleep -Seconds 30
        Write-Verbose -Message "Waiting for VM $NewVMName to complete post-customization reboot." -Verbose
        Wait-Tools -VM $NewVMName -TimeoutSeconds 500 | Out-Null
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 30

        Shutdown-VMGuest $NewVMName -Confirm:$false | Out-Null
    }

    Disconnect-VIServer -Server * -Confirm:$false
}

Function CopyVMToHostAtlanta([string]$VMHost) {

    Connect-VIServer ******************** -User "********************" -Password "********************" | Out-Null

    If ((Get-VMHost $VMHost | Get-VM | Where { $_.Name -like "CED-RDC-PC*" }) -eq $null) {
        $NewVMName = "CED-RDC-PC" + (Get-VMHost $VMHost | Get-VM | Where { $_.Name -like "CED-DC-PC*" }).Name.Substring(9,4)

        New-VM -VMHost $VMHost -Name $NewVMName -Datastore (Get-VMHost $VMHost | Get-VM | Where { $_.Name -like "CED-DC-PC*" } | Get-Datastore).Name -Template "W2k19Std-Template-ATL" -OSCustomizationSpec "Windows Server 2019 Customizations" | Out-Null

        Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
        Start-VM $NewVMName | Out-Null
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 5

        If ((Get-VMHost $VMHost | Get-VM | Where { $_.Name -like "CED-RDC-PC*" }) -eq $null -or (Get-VMHost $VMHost | Get-VM | Where { $_.Name -like "CED-RDC-PC*" }).PowerState -eq “PoweredOff”) {
            Exit
        }

        Write-Verbose -Message "Verifying that Customization for VM $NewVMName has started ..." -Verbose
        While($True) {
            $DCvmEvents = Get-VIEvent -Entity $NewVMName
            $DCstartedEvent = $DCvmEvents | Where { $_.GetType().Name -eq "CustomizationStartedEvent" }
            If ($DCstartedEvent) {
                Break
            }
            Else {
                Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
            }
        }

        Write-Verbose -Message "Customization of VM $NewVMName has started. Checking for Completed Status......." -Verbose
        While($True) {
            $DCvmEvents = Get-VIEvent -Entity $NewVMName
            $DCSucceededEvent = $DCvmEvents | Where { $_.GetType().Name -eq "CustomizationSucceeded" }
            $DCFailureEvent = $DCvmEvents | Where { $_.GetType().Name -eq "CustomizationFailed" }
            If ($DCFailureEvent) {
                Write-Warning -Message "Customization of VM $NewVMName failed" -Verbose
                Break
            }
            If ($DCSucceededEvent) {
                Break
            }
            Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
        }

        Write-Verbose -Message "Customization of VM $NewVMName Completed Successfully!" -Verbose

        Start-Sleep -Seconds 30
        Write-Verbose -Message "Waiting for VM $NewVMName to complete post-customization reboot." -Verbose
        Wait-Tools -VM $NewVMName -TimeoutSeconds 500 | Out-Null
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 30

        Shutdown-VMGuest $NewVMName -Confirm:$false | Out-Null
    }

    Disconnect-VIServer -Server * -Confirm:$false
}

$Functions = [scriptblock]::Create(@"
    Function CopyVMToHostIrving { $Function:CopyVMToHostIrving([string]$myVMHost) }
    Function CopyVMToHostPlano { $Function:CopyVMToHostPlano([string]$myVMHost) }
    Function CopyVMToHostAtlanta { $Function:CopyVMToHostAtlanta([string]$myVMHost) }
"@)

$TotalHostNum = (Get-ADComputer -Server ******************** -SearchBase "OU=********************" -Filter { Name -like "*CED-SQL-PC*" }).Count

While ($Global:CompletedHosts.Count -lt $TotalHostNum) {
    Connect-VIServer ******************** -User "********************" -Password "********************" | Out-Null

    Write-Host "Removing completed hosts from vCenter..."
    ForEach ($VMHost in (Get-VMHost -Location (Get-Datacenter "Profit Centers") | Where-Object { $_.Parent -ne "Upgrade Failures" })) {
        If (((Get-VMHost $VMHost | Get-VM | Where { $_.Name -like "CED-RDC-PC*" }) -ne $null -and $VMHost.Name -notin (Get-Job -State Running).Name.Trim("-TXINTATL")) -or (Get-VMHost $VMHost).ConnectionState -ne "Connected") {
            Remove-VMHost $VMHost -Confirm:$false | Out-Null
            If ($VMHost.Name -notin $Global:CompletedHosts) {
                $Global:CompletedHosts = $Global:CompletedHosts + $VMHost.Name
            }
        }
    }

    Write-Host "Adding additional hosts to vCenter..."
    If ($InputFile) {
        Add-VMHosts -MAXVMHostCount $MAXVMHostCount -InputFile $InputFile
    }
    Else {
        Add-VMHosts -MAXVMHostCount $MAXVMHostCount
    }

    $VMHosts = (Get-VMHost -Location (Get-Datacenter "Profit Centers") | Where-Object { $_.Parent -ne "Upgrade Failures" })

    Disconnect-VIServer -Server * -Confirm:$false

    ForEach ($VMHost in $VMHosts) {
        Write-Host "Checking if max job count has been reached..."
        While ((Get-Job -State Running).Count -ge ($IrvingMaxJobs + $PlanoMaxJobs + $AtlantaMaxJobs)) {
            If (((Get-Date).hour -ge 6 -and (Get-Date).hour -lt 18) -and (Get-Date).DayOfWeek -ne "Saturday" -and (Get-Date).DayOfWeek -ne "Sunday") {
                Write-Host "Total count of hosts that new VM was copied to: $Global:CompletedHosts.Count"
                Exit
            }
            Else {
                Start-Sleep -Seconds 60
            }
        }

        Write-Host "Removing completed jobs..."
        ForEach ($Job in (Get-Job -State Completed)) {
            If ($Job.Name.Trim("-TXINTATL") -notin $GlobalCompletedHosts) {
                $Global:CompletedHosts = $Global:CompletedHosts + $Job.Name.Trim("-TXINTATL")
            }
            Remove-Job -Id $Job.Id
        }

        Write-Host "Starting jobs..."
        If ((Get-Job | Where { $_.Name.Trim("-TXINTATL") -eq $VMHost.Name }) -eq $null -and $VMHost.Name -notin $Global:CompletedHosts) {
            If ((Get-Job | Where { $_.Name -like "*-TX" }).Count -lt $IrvingMaxJobs) {
                Write-Host "Starting job for $VMHost using Irving Source" -ForegroundColor Yellow
                Start-Job -InitializationScript $Functions -Script { CopyVMToHostIrving($Args[0]) } -ArgumentList $VMHost.Name -Name ($VMHost.Name + "-TX") | Out-Null
            }
            ElseIf ((Get-Job | Where { $_.Name -like "*-INT" }).Count -lt $PlanoMaxJobs) {
                Write-Host "Starting job for $VMHost using Plano Source" -ForegroundColor Yellow
                Start-Job -InitializationScript $Functions -Script { CopyVMToHostPlano($Args[0]) } -ArgumentList $VMHost.Name -Name ($VMHost.Name + "-INT") | Out-Null
            }
            ElseIf ((Get-Job | Where { $_.Name -like "*-ATL" }).Count -lt $AtlantaMaxJobs) {
                Write-Host "Starting job for $VMHost using Atlanta Source" -ForegroundColor Yellow
                Start-Job -InitializationScript $Functions -Script { CopyVMToHostAtlanta($Args[0]) } -ArgumentList $VMHost.Name -Name ($VMHost.Name + "-ATL") | Out-Null
            }
        }
    }
}
```